# why is a (1,0) tensor field a contravariant vector field?

Tags: tensors

I know that a contravariant vector field is defined as $\chi: M \to TM $ and a covariant vector field is defined as $\chi^*:M \to T^*M$. And we know that a (1,0) tensor field is defined as $T:\Gamma T^*M \to C^{\infty}(M)$ where $\Gamma T^*M :=\left\{\text{collection of all} \; \chi^*\right\}$. So Now a (1,0) tensor field sends a covariant vector field to a $C^\infty(M)$ function. But how it's also act like e vector field is what I am not getting. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Your notation is a bit unusual: Given a vector bundle $E\to M$ we usually write $\Gamma(M,E)$ for the set of all sections. So $\Gamma(M,T^*M)$ would be the set of all covariant vector fields.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to define vector fields, covector fields and tensor fields. I will use the ones you seem to be using (see the bottom for an alternative). Note that $\Omega^1(M):=\Gamma T^\ast M$.

Given a vector field $\chi:M\to TM$, define an associated map $T_\chi:\Omega^1(M)\to C^\infty(M)$ by $T_\chi(\omega)(x)=\langle \omega(x),\chi(x)\rangle$ for $\omega\in \Omega^1(M)$ and $x\in M$, where the pairing is the natural pairing between the tangent and cotangent spaces at $x\in M$. The harder direction is showing that every $(1,0)$-tensor field arises this way from a vector field. To see this locally, note that given a $(1,0)$-tensor field $T:\Omega^1(M)\to C^\infty(M)$ we can define in local coordinates a vector field

$$\chi_T=\sum_i T(dx^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$

Using partitions of unity, you can extend this to the whole of $M$. It turns out this will be independent of the coordinate charts used. Of course, I am skipping most of the details here, but note that to do it properly you must use the following property of a $(1,0)$-tensor field $T$, namely

> *$C^\infty(M)$-linearity:*
>
> 1. $T(f\omega)=fT(\omega)$ for all $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $\omega\in \Omega^1$.
> 2. $T(\omega_1+\omega_2)=T(\omega_1)+T(\omega_2)$ for $\omega_1,\omega_2\in \Omega^1(M)$.

---

Another way (my preference) this can be done is if we define a $(p,q)$-tensor field as a section of the vector bundle $TM^{\otimes p}\otimes T^\ast M^{\otimes q}\to M$. In this case the proof is trivial, as for $(1,0)$, the vector bundle is just the tangent bundle.

Comment: Thanks. Just for clarity, In terms of arrows is the T defined as $T^*M \to TM \to C^\infty$?

Comment: I don't understand the question i'm afraid. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry let me state it clearly. So we're defining $T$ as the natural pairing between the tangent and cotangent space right? I don't understand how the natural pairing will act on $x$. is it like $\omega(\chi)(x)$?

Comment: $T$ is a tensor field, not the pairing.